# Sending POST request with Postman with @DBref

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, postman

I want to send a POST request with Postman that creates a Purchase object and save it in the database.

My class Purchase:

```
@Document(collection = "purchases")
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private User buyer;
    @DBRef
    private List<File> FilesToPurchase;
    private Long timestamp;

    public Purchase() { }

    public Purchase(User buyer, List<File> filesToPurchase) {
        this.buyer = buyer;
        FilesToPurchase = filesToPurchase;
    }

// Getters and setters not posted here.
```

I want to insert in the database a new purchase done by an already existing User "buyer" who wants to purchase a list of already exsting Files "FilesToPurchase".

I have in my controller a POST function that receives a Purchase object using the annotation @RequestBody, but so far I've got NullPointerExceptions because of the empty Purchase object received.

I don't know how to handle @DBRef annotation. In Postman I try sending a JSON like this:

```
{
    "buyer": {
        "$ref":"users",
       "$id" : "ObjectId('5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a2')"
    },
    "FilesToPurchase": [
     { "$ref":"files",
       "$id" : "ObjectId('5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a5')"
     }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: rename field "FilesToPurchase" and setter to "filesToPurchase" to match java conventions and try this  { "buyer": { "id" : "5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a2" }, "filesToPurchase": [ { "id" : "5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a5" } ] }

Comment: @VladMamaev thank you for the response. I changed the name and did as you told me, and in my post function the object Purchase was created but the "buyer" and "filesToPurchase" inside are empty except for the field "id". Is that behavior okay? Is it because it just store the reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename field "FilesToPurchase" and setter to "filesToPurchase" to match java conventions and try this

```
{ "buyer": { "id" : "5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a2" }, "filesToPurchase": [ { "id" : "5bb5d6634e5a7b2bea75d4a5" } ] }
```

By marking controller parameter with `@RequestBody` you ask Spring to deserialize input json to java object(Jackson ObjectMapper is used by default). It will not automaticly populate the whole `@Dbref` field, you should do it yourself by querying mongo if you want, however the only field you need in referred object to save object that reffers it is 'id'.